# Error running launch4j when attempting to convert jar to exe

Tags: java, build, launch4j

I am running launch4j with the following config.xml (on a mac, os high sierra).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<launch4jConfig>
  <dontWrapJar>false</dontWrapJar>
  <headerType>gui</headerType>
  <jar>/test/wingspan-platform-pdf-assembly-2.3.0-SNAPSHOT.jar</jar>
  <outfile>PdfConverter.exe</outfile>
  <errTitle></errTitle>
  <cmdLine></cmdLine>
  <chdir>.</chdir>
  <priority>normal</priority>
  <downloadUrl>http://java.com/download</downloadUrl>
  <supportUrl></supportUrl>
  <stayAlive>false</stayAlive>
  <restartOnCrash>true</restartOnCrash>
  <manifest></manifest>
  <icon></icon>
  <jre>
    <path></path>
    <bundledJre64Bit>false</bundledJre64Bit>
    <bundledJreAsFallback>false</bundledJreAsFallback>
    <minVersion>1.7.0</minVersion>
    <maxVersion></maxVersion>
    <jdkPreference>preferJre</jdkPreference>
    <runtimeBits>64/32</runtimeBits>
  </jre>
```

However, when I run launch4j, I get the following output.

> launch4j: Resource file: launch4j: LANGUAGE 0, 1 2 RCDATA BEGIN
>   "1.7.0\0" END 18 RCDATA BEGIN "1\0" END 30 RCDATA BEGIN "2\0" END 21
>   RCDATA BEGIN "http://java.com/download\0" END 8 RCDATA BEGIN ".\0" END
>   20 RCDATA BEGIN "32\0" END 31 RCDATA BEGIN "true\0" END 101 RCDATA
>   BEGIN "An error occurred while starting the application.\0" END 102
>   RCDATA BEGIN "This application was configured to use a bundled Java
>   Runtime Environment but the runtime is missing or corrupted.\0" END
>   103 RCDATA BEGIN "This application requires a Java Runtime
>   Environment\0" END 104 RCDATA BEGIN "The registry refers to a
>   nonexistent Java Runtime Environment installation or the runtime is
>   corrupted.\0" END 17 RCDATA BEGIN "true\0" END
>
> launch4j: Compiling resources launch4j: Linking launch4j: Wrapping
>   launch4j: Successfully created
>   /PdfConverter.exe

I don't understand what the problem is, especially since the .exe file gets created. Could someone please let me know how to get rid of the error message?